# Create subdomain and point them to Azure App Service using .net 7

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-app-service

I am building an application where I need to create a separate subdomain per tenant. While registering a new tenant my app should create a subdomain for my main domain which is added to the Azure App Service as a custom domain. I heard that I need to add DNS Zones and etc. but didn't find step-by-step instructions on how to do it with up to date .net 7 code. Will appreciate any help

I am expecting to create subdomains from my .net app and point them to my main domain. I am a bit confused about using CName records or wild card for redirection to the main domain

Comment: You want to create subdomain programmatically or from the Azure App Service in portal?